# Replace in each paragraph

Tags: php, regex

In `$var` there is some code. I'm trying to operate a `nl2br()` on text inside each `<p></p>`.

```
echo preg_replace('/<p>(.*?)</p>/i', nl2br('${1}'), $var);
```

This code doesn't work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: is that a typo on your first example? `text('${1}) // missing closing quote`

Comment: What does `text` do? What does "not work" mean exactly?

Comment: one of the things it do - nl2br()

Comment: so you want to replace anything between `<p></p>` to "something" ?

Comment: @andreas please reread the question

Comment: @steve andreas is correct as that is what your currently on the path to doing...

Comment: Are you 100% sure it will be and stays in that format? Never will there be any attributes on the `p` tags or anything else will change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `preg_replace_callback` might be what you're looking for: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

ETA: In your specific example, you could either use an anonymous function (only if you're doing this once or twice, otherwise it eats up memory) or define a helper function

```
function nl2br_wrapper($matches)
{
    return "<p>".nl2br($matches[1])."</p>";
}

preg_replace_callback('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/si', "nl2br_wrapper", $var);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how can I use it in this context

Comment: [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'p'

Comment: Oops, made a few typos, try it now.

Comment: this regexp gives Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Can you elaborate? What's in $var before you applied this?

Comment: $var has text inside it with new lines, dot is used for "gets everything, except new lines"

Comment: If you want that, you're going to need to add the s modifier to the regex.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>aaaadfg



dfgdfg</p>
            [1] => <p>fgdfgdf</p>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaadfg



dfgdfg
            [1] => fgdfgdf
        )

)

Comment: two same arrays, first one with <p></p>, second one without it

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you trying to still preserve the p tags? That's not what your original template had. But if you want to do that then add them to the nl2br_wrapper function.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to escape `<\/p>`

Answer (score 0):

Like kernal mentions you could use an anonymous function(PHP 5)

```
function replaceText($data, $html)
    {
         $callback = function ($matches) use ($data){
            return ( isset($data[$matches[1]]) ) 
               ? nl2br($data[$matches[1]]) 
               : $matches[0];
        };

        return preg_replace_callback(
                '/\<p>(.*?)\</p>', 
                $callback, 
                $html);
    }

echo replaceText($replace_with, $html);
```